# Organic Groups new group error on group creation

Tags: organic-groups

I am getting the following error when a user tries to create a new group

Can't save entity as group, because user  can't be subscribed to group and become a manager.

The user is subscribed to one group and should be able to create a new one. If they are unsubscribed then this works, even if they are later subscribed.

I would like to look at this page as it may have some useful information but it has a gateway timeout

https://www.drupal.org/node/1538658

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: Drupal.org was experiencing issues today. That issue has a patch that may be useful. Direct link to patch (if having issues still) https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/og-cant-save-entity-as-group-1538658-63.patch

Comment: @MattGlaman Thank you so much. Fixed it straight away